# What resources would you recommend for RPG36 code conversion?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

The question really asks it all. We have a bunch of really old S/36 programs that need to be moderized. I am more looking for articles or sites that explain what the old method does and how to convert it to RPGLE.

Comment: that's a nasty task. I wish you luck with it! :)

Comment: The company I work with has a conversion tool that converts RPGII to vb.net if you were interested in moving off of the 400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/books/c0918180.pdf) for RPG II on the AS400 so you can understand the old code.

You could just trying to compile the code as RPGIII using CRTRPGPGM.  Fix the compile errors on the listing to convert the code to RPG III.

Once you have RPG III source you can continue further to convert it to RPG ILE with the CVTRPGSRC command.

It's might also be possible to take the RPG36 code directly into CVTRPGSRC to convert the source to RPG ILE.

Answer (score 2):

There is no syntactic difference between RPG II and RPG III. You can actually just change the attribute from RPG36 to RPG and it will be "upgraded." You can then run this new member through CVTRPGSRC and get a (usually) useable RPGLE program out of it.

S/36 Procedures, on the other hand, are not as simple to convert.